# Why can be the “:” omitted in python for statements?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I found a statement to unit list, I tried to find information but no good result, can you explain for me?

```
songs = [
     song
     for a in urls
     for b in func(a)
]
```

Comment: This is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not in a normal `for-loop`, but this is a `list comprehension` - they don't share the same syntactical features.